# Cannot send verification email to user on user creation

Tags: meteor

i get no such email for user when calling

```
Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(user._id);
```

i'm using accounts-meld to create user out of social accounts .
it seems the user doesn't have the apropriate email field .

here' my user structure :

```
    { createdAt: Fri Feb 27 2015 18:41:45 GMT+0000 (UTC),
  _id: 'WqQwxMNjkj2',
  services:
    { google:
I20150227-18:41:45.115(0)?       { accessToken: 'dsqfdfsdf',
        expiresAt: 1425066104902,
        id: '117265302061982152409',
        email: 'genjurosama@gmail.com',        verified_email: true,
     name: 'john',
      given_name: 'own',
        family_name: 'Fafa',
        picture: '',
        locale: 'en',
        gender: 'male' } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding "Resend Verification Email" functionality and like you if I try calling:

`Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(user._id, function(error) {...});`

I'm getting the error `No such email address for user`.  And I can clearly see the email address at `user.emails[0].address`. I think this might be a bug because if you call:

`Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(user._id, user.emails[0].address, function(error) {...});`

It works.

The documentation says about the **email** parameter: "*Optional. Which address of the user's to send the email to. This address must be in the user's emails list. Defaults to the first unverified email in the list.*"

So I'm going to report this as a bug.

**EDIT:** It's not a bug.  The `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail` function doesn't take a callback - it's synchronous. So when you pass it a callback it thinks that's the optional email address to send the email to - hence the error.

Source: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5081#event-398306740